# SCDF Stream Design & Custom Processor

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

My current usecase is to receive HTTP Post message, validate it, transform into business object with interested fields (only) and push to nosql db.

I have completed successful poc on http source and mongodb sink on cloud foundry.

For request data validation & transformation, I do not find any available processor so assuming I will have to write one (actually, two).

Can a validation processor generate conditional output? Meaning,

- send valid data to queue for further processing (here, transformation)?
- send invalid data to log/error processing in mongodb sink?

Or should I design my stream in a different way? Appreciate your guidence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; you can use a `StreamBridge` to select where to send the output.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Very helpful.
I am trying to follow the reference link and created a simple HTTP listener app that receives POST msg and validate incoming message with schema class. All I do is, when an app receive POST msg, it will print the message on console and send it to RMQ using StreamBridge send method.

I am seeing connection denied error when I deploy the war (in CF) using SCDF. And hence, the message is not received by RMQ. However, if I deploy the war using cf push, it works just fine.

Do I have any additional RMQ configurations to do in WAR?